# How to automate python scripts on a web apache server

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

I want to create an automatic script in python that will inform me with an email when a new order is placed on my website.
So far, I found I can use cronjobs from the apache server every minute, but it seems to be overkill since I don't get orders every minute.

So I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: You can set the `cronjob` to be every 30 minutes, 1 hours, or whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you. but as i said it seems to be over kill. I need the script to run everytime that there is a new web order.

Comment: I strongly recommend `celery`

Comment: @wakeZheng Thank you i will check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s the code you can call this code whenever the order is placed by the user you don’t need to automate

If you are using django you can use this:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

Without django you can use this :

```
import smtplib

sender = 'from@example.com'
receivers = ['to@example.com']

message = “This is a test e-mail message."

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
   print "Successfully sent email"
except SMTPException:
   print "Error: unable to send email"
```